# JxMapviewer problem

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to add a jxmapviewer control in my form using netbeans and when i drag the object from the palette I get the following error.

A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred.
Please report this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html,
including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.
The messages.log file is located in your

I have imported the control from the swing-ws.jar "as a jar file".

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had the following jar files missing.

```
 swingx-bean.jar
 swingx.jar
 swing-worker.jar
```

Thanks anyway.